# Getting list of users from firebase database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, swift5

I want to get list of users from firebase, I am following a tutorial which is not using swift 5, but I am writing my code in swift 5. I am pretty new to swift and iOS development.
How can I convert the following code to swift 5

I have a users in firebase database which ~I am trying to retrieve, and each user has `email` and `name`

User

```
class User: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var email: String?
}
```

Trying to convert below code to swift 5

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child(“users”).observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
   If let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

   }
}, withCancelBlock: nil)
```

This is what I have done, and I don't think I am getting the data right

```
func fetchUsers() {
        
        Database.database().reference().child("users").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

            if let dictionary  = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let user = User()
                user.setValuesForKeys(dictionary) // this is where my error is

            }
        }
    }
```

Error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<FBCHSRM.User 0x600002701050> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key email.'
```

Data in the dictionary looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you are setting values wrongly you should change something. first add your user struct

```
init(email: String, username: String) {
        self.email= email
        self.name = name

    }
```

then make an array of users to store data as:

```
var users:[User] = []
```

in fetchUser func

```
 if let dictionary  = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        for dic in dictionary{
            let emailFromFB = dic["email"] as? String ?? "" 
            let username = dic["username"] as? String ?? "" /
            var u: User(email: email, name:name)
            users.append(u)

        }
    }

    print(users)
```